# Extra spaces added before line break on inserting page break (Ctrl+Enter)

Tags: microsoft-word

If I insert a page break using either menu or shortcut the last line on the page contains a bunch of spaces. What is it and how do I ge rid of it?

Comment: What problem does this cause

Comment: @Dave These spaces get added at the top of new page and all the formatting is lost. If it is a feature how is it helpful?

Answer (score 1):

Based on my tests and researching, it seems to be a normal behavior by design.

You will find the space in the last line on the page is hidden mark of page break if you [show paragraph marks](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/show-or-hide-tab-marks-in-word-84a53213-5d02-404a-b022-09cae1a3958b) on the home tab or Word Options (File > Options > Display).

[image]

The blank line at the top of next page come with the page break at the same time if you insert a page break at the end of a paragraph. You can delete the line if you want.

[image]

If you insert the page break at the starting of a paragraph, the blank line won't be added at the top of the next page:

[image]

However, if you clear the space in the last line on the page, the page break will be removed.

Reference: [Insert a page break](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/insert-a-page-break-7613ff46-96e5-4e46-9491-40d7d410a043);
[Line and page breaks](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/line-and-page-breaks-419441d0-0963-4cfe-a79f-57c83b92e5ae);
[Line and page breaks](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/line-and-page-breaks-954955be-8779-4950-bbab-652cebe8e200).